# Website Progress Indicator

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have been using a progress indicator with an update panel and it works great.

What I am asking is how to show a progress indicator on a button click that populates data on the page form the database. The situation is that I have to get a lot of information form the database on button click and I want the user to see a progress indicator while this happens.

Is the best thing to just surround it with an update panel? Should I programatically control the progress indicator from each button handler?

Even show this while pages are being changed or posted back. Like show progress indicator between navigation from page 1 to page 2.

I just want to know the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your update panel update mode as conditional and then add asynchronous triggers for all your buttons. you don't want to surround it with an update panel.